# I getting the Error on product page magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, rest-api, repository

[image]

I tried to update the product using REST API but it shows the page this like i can't recognise the error please any one help to resolve it.
Header : **rest/all/V1/products/SKU**
My API :

```
{
   "product":{
      "id":10,
      "sku":"SKU",
      "name":"My product name",
      "attribute_set_id":4,
      "status":1,
      "visibility":4,
      "type_id":"simple",
      "weight":"0.0",
      "extension_attributes":{
         "category_links":[
            {
               "position":0,
               "category_id":"99",
               "extension_attributes":{



               }
            }
         ],
         "stock_item":{
            "qty":"0",
            "is_in_stock":true,
            "extension_attributes":{



            }
         }
      },
      "custom_attributes":[

         {
            "attribute_code":"manufacturer",
            "value":"5824"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I find the line in UI DataProvide **( vendor\magento\module-catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider.php )**

> **$this->getCollection()->toArray()**

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using docker try

```
dockergento magento c:f
```

if not try

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

about error try if (!isset ... ->toArray())
or try removing toArray at all.